# Inputting data into a paired list

Tags: python

Below is the code I am currently working with. Im trying to make it so I can add a second piece of data after the name so it reads (name1,data1),(name2,data2),(name3,data3). Is there a function that allows me to do this?

```
ListOfNames = []
while True:
    Name = input('Input Band Member')
    if Name != "":
        ListOfNames.append(Name)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the information in two separate lists if you will and zip them together with `zip()` in the end.

You can try like so:

```
namel = []
bandl = []
while True:
    n = input("Enter Name: ")
    if n != '':
        d1 = input("Enter data1: ")
        namel.append(n)
        bandl.append(d1)
    else:
        break

print(list(zip(namel, bandl)))
```

Demo output:

```
Enter Name: Rupee
Enter data1: India
Enter Name: Dollar
Enter data1: USA
Enter Name: 
[('Rupee', 'India'), ('Dollar', 'USA')]
```

Or if you make sure the user enters 2 values separated by comma, you can try it like so:

```
l = []
while True:
    n = input("Enter Name: ")
    if n!='':
        l.append(n.split(','))
    else:
        break

print(l)
```

Demo run:

```
Enter Name: Rupee, India
Enter Name: Dollar, USA
Enter Name: 
[['Rupee', ' India'], ['Dollar', ' USA']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special function, just append a list instead of a string:

```
ListOfNames.append([Name, data])
```

Or, if you don't know what the data will be until later:

```
ListOfNames.append([Name])
```

and then:

```
ListOfNames[x].append(data)
```

Where `x` is the index of whatever list you want to append to.

Alternatively, if you prefer to build up the two lists independently first, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to merge them them.

```
zip(ListOfNames, data_list)
```

That may or may not be more appropriate depending on your program's structure. Without knowing how or when or in what order your data_list is gathered, it's hard to say.